# How to Create a Search Field in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react, and I'm working on a small project that uses a search bar to find data that I've gotten from my database.

The code for this component is below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class BodyData extends Component {
    state = {
        query: '',
        data: [],
    }

    handleInputChange = () => {
        this.setState({
            query: this.search.value
        })
        this.filterArray();
    }

    getData = () => {
        fetch(`http://localhost:4000/restaurants`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(responseData => {
            // console.log(responseData)
            this.setState({
                data:responseData
            })
        })
    }

    filterArray = () => {
        var searchString = this.state.query;
        var responseData = this.state.data
        if(searchString.length > 0){
            // console.log(responseData[i].name);
            responseData = responseData.filter(l => {
                console.log( l.name.toLowerCase().match(searchString));
            })
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.getData();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="searchForm">
                <form>
                    <input type="text" id="filter" placeholder="Search for..." ref={input => this.search = input} onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>
                </form>
                <div>
                    {
                        this.state.data.map((i) =>
                            <p>{i.name}</p>
                        )
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default BodyData;
```

So basically, I want to update the state as I type in the query text, and have the restaurant names I've mapped be reduced till a match is found.

From what I understood, `this.state.data` will be filtered as I type in my query in the search bar. However when I map out `this.state.data`, I get the whole list of restaurants instead of what I want to see.

Ive been through a bunch of tutes, and I'm not exactly sure how to go about doing that.

Can anyone help me with this please? Any other comments on the code are also welcome. I'm here to learn :)

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please share your Restaurants file with me? I am stuck on a similar thing only. Is your Restaurant a json file? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could keep an additional piece of state called e.g. `filteredData` that contains all elements in `data` that include your `query` in the name, and then render that.

**Example**

```
class BodyData extends React.Component {
  state = {
    query: "",
    data: [],
    filteredData: []
  };

  handleInputChange = event => {
    const query = event.target.value;

    this.setState(prevState => {
      const filteredData = prevState.data.filter(element => {
        return element.name.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase());
      });

      return {
        query,
        filteredData
      };
    });
  };

  getData = () => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:4000/restaurants`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        const { query } = this.state;
        const filteredData = data.filter(element => {
          return element.name.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase());
        });

        this.setState({
          data,
          filteredData
        });
      });
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    this.getData();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="searchForm">
        <form>
          <input
            placeholder="Search for..."
            value={this.state.query}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          />
        </form>
        <div>{this.state.filteredData.map(i => <p>{i.name}</p>)}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Tholle, may I trouble you to explain the `handleInputChange` function to me?
I don't understand this bit 
`return element.name.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase());`

Comment: @jerome Sure! It casts the element name to lower case and the query to lower case, and then checks if the query is contained inside the name, e.g. `tho` is contained inside `tholle`. Every element that matches in this way is included in the filtered data.

Comment: Thank you, @Tholle. I get that bit now! Then in `getData()` the same filtering is done again when the component mounts?

Comment: @jerome Great! Yes, that's right. A quick user might have already inserted a query in the input when the data is loaded, so it might be a good idea to filter the data right away when you set it in state for the first time.

Comment: Awesome. I get it now. Thanks @Tholle

Answer (score 5):

Here is the code that will work for you

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class BodyData extends Component {

state = {
    query: '',
    data: [],
    searchString:[]
}

handleInputChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        query: event.target.value
    },()=>{
  this.filterArray();
})

}

getData = () => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:4000/restaurants`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseData => {
        // console.log(responseData)
        this.setState({
            data:responseData,
            searchString:responseData
        })
    })
}

filterArray = () => {
    let searchString = this.state.query;
    let responseData = this.state.data;



    if(searchString.length > 0){
        // console.log(responseData[i].name);
        responseData = responseData.filter(searchString);
this.setState({
   responseData
})
    }

}

componentWillMount() {
    this.getData();
}
render() {
    return (
        <div className="searchForm">
            <form>
                <input type="text" id="filter" placeholder="Search for..."  onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>
            </form>
            <div>
                {
                    this.state.responseData.map((i) =>
                        <p>{i.name}</p>
                    )
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
  }
}


export default BodyData;
```

There are few changes which is needed.

1. Set State is worked asynchronous.SO, to avoid it use arrow function when you need to do something immediately  after set state.
2. there are 2 different keyword in es6 instead of var. **Let** and **Const** . use them instead of var.
3. There is no need of ref in input. you can directly get value of input by event.target.value

Enjoy Coding!!

Comment: Where exactly did you use "searchString:[]"? I am trying to implement that mechanism to my code but when I type something to the form it gives "is not a function" error

Answer (score 0):

[setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) method is asynchronous and it has second parameter - callback that is called when the state is applied.

You need to change `handleInputChange` methods.

```
handleInputChange = () => {
    this.setState({
        query: this.search.value
    }, this.filterArray)
}
```

Comment: Wait, so when the state is applied the call back (filterArray) is triggered?

Comment: That's correct! And `this.state` will contain data that you passed to `this.setState` method.

Comment: Check out [this](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/functional-setstate-is-the-future-of-react-374f30401b6b) link to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Few pointers I'll like to show-

1. `setState({})` function is asynchronous, you'll have to either use functional `setState` and call `filteredArray` method as a callback. Or, call `filteredArray` at `render`, which is where your values will be updated and be reflected.
2. Your `filterArray` method is not returning / setting the filtered list of data. So what you type, even though it is getting filtered, it is not getting set / returned anywhere.